# convert range of dates into sequence of integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, finance

I have a dataframe of several different dates of financial information, which looks like this.

```
    symbol  split_date  date_start  date_end    marketCap   Date        Adj Close        Volume
0   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-02-28  6.300000190734862 22010.0
1   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-02  6.0999999046325675   7300.0
2   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-03  6.5 9700.0
3   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-04  7.0 13340.0
4   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-05  6.9000000953674325  5510.0
5   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-06  6.4000000953674325  5790.0
6   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-09  6.300000190734862   10080.0
7   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-10  6.0 14630.0
8   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-11  5.300000190734863   20160.0
9   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-12  4.699999809265137   17390.0
```

In this dataframe, I have 577 different symbols (more than just `USAU`). All dates in `Date` column are different ranges, as they're all centered around a specific event happening.

I am trying to create a column which, for each ticker in the dataset with unique date range, assigns an integer (1-10) to the dates for grouping.

Pseudocode:

```
for symbol in symbols_in_dataframe:
    convert date of symbol to integer

# IE
# Symbol: A YYYY/MM/01 -> 1
# Symbol: A YYYY/MM/02 -> 2
# .....
# Symbol: A YYYY/MM/10 -> 10
    This loops through each symbol.

# Symbol: B YYYY/MM/01 -> 1
# Symbol: B YYYY/MM/02 -> 2
# .....
# Symbol: B YYYY/MM/10 -> 10
```

I gave this a shot but this is not the outcome I am wanting.

```
def to_integer(dt_time):
    return 10000*dt_time.year + 100*dt_time.month + dt_time.day

blank_df = pd.dataframe()
for symbol in symbols_in_dataframe:
    blank_df.map(symbol, to_integer)
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

Expected output of dataframe:

```
    symbol  split_date  date_start  date_end    marketCap   Date    Adj Close   Volume   Num_seq
0   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-02-28  6.3     22010.0    1
1   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-02  6.1     7300.0     2
2   USAU    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  45773136    2020-03-03  6.5     9700.0     3
44  INLX    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  19112184    2020-02-21  4.50    0.0        1
45  INLX    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  19112184    2020-02-24  4.00    600.0      2
46  INLX    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  19112184    2020-02-25  4.00     20.0      3
95  OMWS    2020-03-19  2020-02-27  2020-04-30  92829984    2021-04-12  0.25    1000.0     1
96  OMWS    2020-03-19  2020-02-27  2020-04-30  92829984    2021-04-14  0.25    6502.0     2
97  OMWS    2020-03-19  2020-02-27  2020-04-30  92829984    2021-04-16  0.25    0.0        3
```

Essentially, for each instance of `symbol`, I am trying to assign a count of each symbol in a the dataframe, here seen under `Num_seq` for number in sequence, if that makes sense.

You should be able to use the above dataframe as a reference.

---

EDIT with code sample from comment:

It seems it's making duplicates and sequencing on every other index entry on dataframe in an alternating format. I'm not entirely sure what is being edited with the code, though, as `split_date`, `date_start`, and `date_end` should not be changed.

```
    symbol  split_date  date_start  date_end    marketCap   Date    Adj Close   Volume  seq
44  INLX    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  19112184    2020-02-21  4.500000    0.0     1
68  INLX    2020-03-13  2020-02-21  2020-04-24  19112184    2020-02-21  4.500000    0.0     1
45  INLX    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  19112184    2020-02-24  4.000000    600.0   2
69  INLX    2020-03-13  2020-02-21  2020-04-24  19112184    2020-02-24  4.000000    600.0   2
46  INLX    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  19112184    2020-02-25  4.000000    20.0    3
70  INLX    2020-03-13  2020-02-21  2020-04-24  19112184    2020-02-25  4.000000    20.0    3
47  INLX    2020-03-20  2020-02-28  2020-05-01  19112184    2020-02-26  4.000000    0.0     4
71  INLX    2020-03-13  2020-02-21  2020-04-24  19112184    2020-02-26  4.000000    0.0     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `groupby` and `cumsum` to assign increasing numbers to each unique Date in each unique symbol. Not sure if this is exactly what you want or not, please comment if I misinterpreted

Here is an example with a similar dataset to the one you posted

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'symbol':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c'],
    'values':[8,9,9,9,10,11,12,13]
})

df = df.sort_values(['symbol','values']) #if table is not already sorted. for you it would be ['symbol','Date']

df['x'] = (
    df.groupby('symbol')['values'] #group by symbol
      .transform(lambda v: (~v.duplicated()).cumsum()) #assign numbers, avoiding duplicate counting
)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  symbol  values  x
0      a       8  1
1      a       9  2
2      a       9  2
3      b       9  1
4      b      10  2
5      b      11  3
6      c      12  1
7      c      13  2
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I'm going after. I have edited OP for a better example of dataframe expectations.

Comment: EDIT-ish: Upon reading, I'm not sure if your code is displaying `x` as a typo in row 2 or if that's expected output.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I think something like `df['Num_seq'] = df.groupby('symbol').cumcount()` is what you need. I'm sorry I don't understand about `x` but please run my example code yourself and let me know if there is an error

Comment: df['Num_seq'] = df.groupby('symbol').cumcount() did the trick, thank you so much!